# Haskell data vs class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've written an LALR1 parser which seems to work. It can be parameterised for the type of symbols it receives. The only binding is `Eq`.

```
module LALR.Parser where

data Rule symbolT = Rule 
    {
        lhs :: symbolT,
        rhs :: Int
    }

data Action symbolT = Accept
    | Goto (State symbolT)
    | Shift (State symbolT)
    | Reduce (Rule symbolT)

data State symbolT = State
    {
        transitions :: [ (symbolT, Action symbolT) ]
    }

data Parser symbolT = Parser
    {
        states :: [State symbolT],
        input  :: [symbolT]
    }

data Result symbolT = UnexpectedSymbol symbolT
    | Accepted
    | Pending (Parser symbolT)
    | EmptyInput
    | EmptyStack

build :: State symbolT -> [symbolT] -> Parser symbolT
build state input = Parser
    {
        states = [state],
        input = input
    }

step :: Eq symbolT => Parser symbolT -> Result symbolT
step (Parser [] _) = EmptyStack
step (Parser _ []) = EmptyInput
step parser@(Parser states@(state : statesTail) input@(lookAhead : inputTail) ) = case (action) of
    Nothing                            -> UnexpectedSymbol lookAhead
    Just Accept                        -> Accepted
    Just (Shift target)                -> Pending (Parser (target : states) inputTail)
    Just (Reduce rule@(Rule lhs rhs) ) -> Pending (Parser (drop rhs states) (lhs : input) )
    Just (Goto target)                 -> Pending (Parser (target : states) inputTail )
    where
        action = lookup lookAhead (transitions state)

run :: Eq symbolT => Parser symbolT -> Result symbolT
run parser = case (step parser) of
    Pending parser -> run parser
    result         -> result
```

However, now I want to transform this parser into a compiler, which not only accepts or rejects a given input, but actually converts it into something useful. Basically, I am thinking to add a handler which can handle the different actions taken. Now my question is the following:

The compiler will require not only to receive mere Symbols, but Symbols with bells and whistles, e.g. a payload (whatever the lexer lexed), or a line number, a file name, or something else.

In an object oriented language I would recur to inheritance and derive a class from Symbol. But what is the way to go in Haskell?

Should I define a `class Token` which requires a function `symbol :: Token -> Symbol` and then I would create some data structure that instances that class? Changing the bindings from `Eq symbolT` to `Token symbolT` and then calling `symbol` when I need to lookup the symbol?

(I am trying to study the language limiting myself mostly to the Prelude.)

UPDATE:

> Your entire code is parameterised by symbolT. Why just not assume that symbolT is a symbol with a payload? Do you want different types of payload for different symbols?

Yes, I want different payloads. The Lexer produces a `[Token]`.

```
data Token = Assignment | Name String | Number Int

lex :: String -> Maybe [Token]
```

I could derive `Eq` so that it ignores the payload, e.g.

```
instance Eq Token where
    (==) (Name _) (Name _) = True
    -- etc
```

but then in the definition of the `transitions` of the states I would need to give it a dummy token e.g. `[ (Number 0, Accept), (Name "", Shift state3) ]` which looks kind of wrong.

I was thinking about something like:

```
class Tkn a symbolT where
    symbol :: a -> symbolT
```

and then when I lookup the transitions, I would call that method to extract the symbol.

I am not sure if I am explaining myself or if any of this makes any sense.

Comment: You might look at [regex-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative-0.3.4/docs/src/Text.Regex.Applicative.Types.html#RE) for inspiration here. An `RE s a` is a regex that parses symbols of type `s` and produces payloads of type `a`.

Comment: Your entire code is parameterised by `symbolT`. Why just not assume that `symbolT` is a symbol with a payload? Do you want different types of payload for different symbols?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you very much for you comment. I have updated my question in case you have the time to take another look.

Comment: If you want different types of payloads for different symbols, then perhaps classes are not what you need, because a signature like `run :: Token symbolT => Parser symbolT -> Result symbolT` still works with the same type of symbolT. You can instantiate *different* parsers with different symbol payloads but that's probably not what you want.